# How do I migrate static aws website to dynamic

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a personal website hosted on aws using s3, cloudfront and route53, but as time goes by I would like to have some dynamic functionalities such as allowing visitors to leave a private message. May I know what is the best option for me? Should I use an EC2 instance? Or Lambda + API gateway... etc?

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you start at [Choose Your Web Application Infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/guides/deploy-webapp-decision/) because there is no single answer.

> There are different factors to take into account when deciding which service to use to deploy your first web application on the AWS Cloud. You should consider if you want a managed infrastructure with low stress, if you need containers (and why) or if you want full control and customization.

Comment: Thanks! did not know such a page exists!

Answer (score 1):

As I think you currently don't have server-side rendering type of setup that is great news for you to host a personal website, For any dynamic backend related stuff you can use AWS Lambda functions for contact forms submissions and other things and the price would also no very low to host these rather than switching to ec2